# Getting the previous working directory value

Tags: unix, awk, pwd

here is my simple command.

```
ls -lrth ../ | grep file | awk -F" " -v orig=`cd .. | pwd ` -v sort=`pwd` '{print $NF "," $7"/"$8"/"$9","orig"," sort }'
```

I'm trying to get the value of my previous path  just above my current working directory.

current working directory = /home/PC1/Environment/Test1

what i want to get the value of pwd is /home/PC1/Environment and not want to hardcode it.

i tried to use cd .. | pwd but it still displays my current working directory not my previous working directory

can anyone help? some suggestions would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(cd .. && pwd)`.  You can also use `$(cd - && pwd)` to get your previous working directory even if it wasn't the parent of your current one.  (In general, you should use `$(`...`)` instead of `...` to get command output; the latter interferes with quoting and doesn't nest, so can cause surprising results).

Your `cd | pwd` runs the `cd` and the `pwd` at the same time in different subshells, which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks!, that works perfectly!  and i really appreciate your explanation to it.